# mysql group by where another field is the same

Tags: mysql

I have a database full of train movement data when a train enters a stations we may get an arrival message and when the train leaves the station to head to the next destination we may get a departure message.

therefore when a train hits a station we will normally get 2 messages 1 for when it arrived and 1 for when it departed. However sometimes there are mistakes in this data and so we can get another movement message to correct the departure/arrival data. If a movement message is a correction of a previous one it will have a correction_ind of 1 otherwise it will have a correction_ind of 0.

This means that for a given station we can have a total of 4 messages (departure, arrival, fixed departure, fixed arrival)

I'm trying to get 0/1 departure messages and 0/1 arrival messages for each station along a route for a specific train. Where we select movement message in the following order:

- Pick the fixed message (if it exists) otherwise
- Pick the first movement message (if it exists) otherwise
- don't pick anything

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    tm.variation_status,
    tm.planned_timestamp,
    tm.platform,
    tm.actual_timestamp,
    tm.event_type,
    tm.timetable_variation,
    sched.tps_description
FROM
    train_activation ta,
    train_movement tm
        LEFT JOIN
    cif_tiploc sched ON sched.stanox = tm.loc_stanox
WHERE
    train_uid = 'C40200'
        AND date(creation_timestamp) = '2014-08-20'
        AND tm.train_id = ta.train_id
ORDER BY tm.correction_ind ASC
```

the problem I have with this query is for a given station we can get 0-2 departure messages and 0-2 arrival messages. If I add the following `GROUP BY tm.event_type` (this is the field that tells us if this is a departure or arrival message) we will only get 2 messages in total as it will group all the depature's together and all the arrivals together!

how can I re-write this query so we only select the best arrival/depature message for a each station along the route?

1. a station can be identified by `tm.loc_stanox` or sched.tps_description
2. a message will tell us if its an depart or arrival by `tm.event_type`
3. a message will tell us if its a correction to a previous message by `tm.correction_ind` which will be 1 if its a correction or 0 if its not

any help on the issue would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying an order by case/when condition, but for each respective station.

order by
    tm.loc_stanox,
    case when tm.event_type like 'fixed%' then 1
         when tm.event_type like 'arrive%' then 2
         when tm.event_type like 'depart%' then 3 end

I wish I had more sample data to see the real scenarios you are describing to better assist.